# Custom BLE HID keyboard keypresses is not appeared in macOS

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth

I am developing custom BLE HID keyboard using Raspberry Pi.
Raspberry Pi 400 is playing the role of the peripheral Bluetooth Low Energy HID Device.

I managed to make it work on Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 8, Samsung Galaxy S23 with Android 13, and on the laptop with Windows 10.

But it does not work on MacBook M2 Pro with Ventura 13.5. My Raspberry Pi based keyboard successfully paired with MacBook. I have trace Bluetooth traffic on Raspberry Pi with the help of Wireshark and on the MacBook with PacketLogger and it shows that packets with HID Reports are sent by Raspberry PI and received by MacBook.

And for some reason it seems they are ignored by macOS and when I open text editor it does not see keypresses.

when I run `ioreg -c IOHIDInterface` I can not find my Bluetooth Low energy device in the result of the command.

Is there way to find the reason of such behavior? Are there tools in macOS to get more info for this case. For example `ktrace` ulity.
Or the reason why my keyboard was not added to IO Registry?